# Is it possible to move the background image?

Tags: android, image, background-image

I have set my background image by using code below

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@mipmap/background_image"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

My page with the background image

[image]

I wonder is there has a way to adjust the background  image size and can move the image to left hand side ?

Comment: Don't use `AbsoluteLayout`

Comment: @Emmanuel Then what should I use?

Comment: You would use an `ImageView`. Set the image as it `src` and position it using a `RelativeLayout` or another `ViewGroup`.

Comment: @Emmanuel Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to adjust background image, then you should use ImageView as a First Child of FrameLayout or RelativeLayout and you can arrange the remaining controls as per your requirement in Second Child or remaining child.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BitmapDrawable` to adjust background's place.
   But you should get right size mipmap for it.
    back.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:gravity="left|top">
</bitmap>


android:background="@drawable/back"
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO.